# Objective-C iOS Application - Symbol(s) not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

This is my code:

```
- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation {
    if([operation isEqual:@"sqrt"])
        operand = srqt(operand);
    return operand;
}
```

And this is the error that is preventing my app from running

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_srqt", referenced from:
      -[CalculatorBrain performOperation:] in CalculatorBrain.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Heeeelp! :D

Comment: OMG, it does deserves a #FAIL

Comment: When you do string comparison, use isEqualToString: instead of isEqual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if([operation isEqual:@"sqrt"])
    operand = srqt(operand);
```

Notice that you have misspelled the `sqrt` function in the second line. That is, unless you have defined your own `srqt` function. But according to the linker error, it seems that you have not.

Answer (score 5):

yo wrote `operand = srqt(operand);` but meant `operand = sqrt(operand);`

Answer (score 0):

It is `sqrt` not `srqt`. and seven more characters to prove I'm human...

Answer (score 0):

OK, do this

```
#include <math.h>
```

Then check your spelling on srqt(), it should be sqrt().